# standalone scenebuilder to get intellij project

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, scenebuilder

Okay, I may get responses to read the manual - I did review and did google searches and I am just not seeing it.
I have created a UI using a standalone Scenebuilder. I have a working Kotlin code in intellij. Basically all I want to do is getting what I created from the standalone Scenebuilder to intellij in my Kotlin project so that I can connect them. Get my Kotlin code that works at on the command prompt to give it some life in a GUI. I am still in the learning stages of programming in Kotlin and using Scenebuilder (standalone).

If anyone can point me on where I would find how to provide this connectivity, I would really appreciate it -- thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some code to show your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you talk about JavaFX. There is a JavaFX Framework for Kotlin called tornadoFx. You can check that out here https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx

If you use the SceneBuilder (and therefore FXML), have also a look at that documentation: https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/10.%20FXML.html

Comment: thanks for response and providing the tornadofx links! I read the manual last night and seen how to interconnect standalone Scenebuilder to Intellij. Tornadofx framework looks very promising and will get started learning on its use.